# get rid of temporary saved managedObjectContext

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

how can I manage temporary saved CoreData? 
as soon as I do something like this:

```
var myClass: MyClass = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MyClass", inManagedObjectContext: (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!) as MyClass
```

it is part of my managedObjectContext and will be saved when i do a `context.save(nil)`
Is there any way to get an object of the NSManagedObject Class without messing with my current context.
In other words: I want to have optional objects that just end up unused when I don't save them explicitly and i want to have objects that I really want to save persistently.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is late but hopefully helps someone else out there. **Yes there is.** You create a child context. Do anything you want there. If 
you want to keep your changes, save the child context - which does NOT persist data. It notifies parent context of the changes, the changes are now in your main context.  You can then perform save on the main context.

```
    let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    childContext.parentContext = mainContext
    guard let myClass = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MyClass", inManagedObjectContext: childContext) as? MyClass else {
        // something went wrong, handle it here
        return
    }
    // do your thing here
```

to let the main context know that you want to keep your changes:

```
    do {
        try childContext.save()  // does not persist anything, just lets know the parent that we are happy with the changes
    } catch {
        // handle error
    }
```

when you want to NOT keep your changes you can reset:

```
    childContext.reset()
```

when you want to persist the changes on the main context you do as always:

```
    do {
         try mainContext.save()
    } catch {
         // handle error
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much... exact answer as i needed.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way u can get rid of updated object what you can do is update it again with real data (which is previous data before updating). whenever you update object of 'NSManagedObject' (core data entity object) 'NSManagedObjectContext' captures all the changes and it saves whenever you do save context.

In this type of use case better to use Sqlite database.

Comment: thanks for your answer! what do you exactly mean by "update it again with real data" ?

Comment: don't do save context when you don't wanna save data,but still if you wanna do save context because you might have created new entity.but before doing save context update your updated object with original data(which is real data).

Comment: But how do I update the object? And what kind of object do you mean??

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the objects from the managed context before you call `context.save`, which prevents them from being committed. Assuming you have an `NSManagedObjectContext` called `context` and an instance of `MyClass` called `myClass`, then the following will work:

`context.deleteObject(myClass)`

See:

> [NSManagedObjectContext.deleteObject](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/deleteObject:)
>
> **Discussion**
>
> ... If object has not yet been saved to a persistent store, it is simply removed from the receiver.

Of course the decision about which objects to save and which to discard are up to the logic of your application. So before you call save, you need to check all of the inserted, but not yet, committed instances that are registered with the NSManagedObjectContext you're using. You can keep track of that in your application, or perhaps this will be of use:

> [NSManagedObjectContext.insertedObjects](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSManagedObjectContext/insertedObjects)
>
> The set of objects that have been inserted into the receiver but not yet saved in a persistent store. (read-only)